# Sending values as parameters to check if exist or not into mongodb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, lambda

Hi i'm using lambda function to check a username and password in a mongodb which is run in local.

```
module.exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  console.log('login');
  const { username, password } = JSON.parse(event.body);
  console.log("username--->",username);
  console.log("password-->",password)

  try {
    // Authenticate user
    const user = users.login(username, password);
    console.log("----->inside login handler!!!",user);
```

this is where i am sending the values to check in the db

```
login = function (username, password) {
    console.log("--------inside login of users",username,password)
    userRegister.findOne({
      username : username,
      password : password
    }).then(function(err,data){
      if (err) {
        console.log("---------------err", err)
        return _.omit(err);
      }
      else {
        console.log("---------------data", data)
        return _.omit(data);
      }
    })
  }
```

the value is not returning anything, im getting undefined!
the findOne is not working i think!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Using find with values supplied by the user makes you vulnerable for injections e.g:

```
"username": {"$gt": ""}
"password": {"$gt": ""}
```

I would use a third party like [passport](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/) local authentication.

You could at least find the user by the username and then validate the username and password with '==='.

As for the findOne returns undefined, try to execute the same query with a tool like [Robomongo](https://robomongo.org/) your syntax seems to be correct.

Comment: "username": {"$gt": ""}
"password": {"$gt": ""} i don't get this, what are you trying to say

Comment: With this query a hacker will be able to log in with the first user in your database, without knowing its credentials at all. (Any string is greater than empty string) If you are familiar with sql injection it is equivalent to 'or 1==1'

Answer (score 0):

Why are you matching password. In findOne I believe that you should have hashed you password before storing them to the database. If not I heavenly recommend doing so. Match the password after you have found the document using you hashing library

```
 login = function (username, password) {
    console.log("--------inside login of users",username,password)
    userRegister.findOne({
      username : username // Remove password from here
    }).then(function(err,data){
      if (err) {
        console.log("---------------err", err)
        return _.omit(err);
      }
      else {
        // Match password here
        console.log("---------------data", data)
        return _.omit(data);
      }
    })
   }
```